# set 5 divs in the same positions jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I set the location of 5 divs (equally in dimension) in the same position after initializing with jQuery.

The reason I want to have this is to move them one by one to another div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start by accepting the 50+ questions you've already asked, and after that, maybe learn some CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends largely on the HTML you have, but the general ideal is to set the CSS `position` attribute of each element to be `absolute`, and then set their positions to be the same using a combination of the `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` CSS properties.

```
$('yourDivs').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0
});
```

This assumes that the the `div`'s are in the same parent, or that none of their ancestors has a `position: relative` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Gab4B/

```
div
{
 height: 200px;
  width: 200px;  
}

div div {
 height: 20px;
  width: 20px;  
    border: solid 1px black;
}
div.seperate-equal
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
   background-color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set CSS `position: absolute`, with equal `top` and `left`...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some position absolute. [Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eAh2T/)

```
$('.class').each(function(){ 
    this.style.top=0; 
    this.style.left=0; 
    this.style.position='absolute'
});
```